# Force disable dark mode in android application not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

**I have force disable dark mode in my android application but still the app is in dark mode when my phone is in dark mode**

I have also changed the theme for both light and night modes to light theme with no action bar but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)Add this line in each activity just below onCreate

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

**OR**

2. add this line in your themes under style section

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
```